# PhantomJs is breaking for polymer application

Tags: java, selenium, polymer, phantomjs, shadow-dom

PhantomJS version : 2.1

Problem : My company just made a UI change in the app by using polymer and app url now contain `/?dom=shadow`. Due to this phantomJS is breaking during sendKeys to input element.

**Html Element :**

```
<input type="text" class="GO43PFXOS GO43PFXDK" id="tbUsername" placeholder="Username" maxlength="50" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 310px; height: 30px; text-align: left;">
```

**Code example :**

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "lib//phantomjs");
    WebDriver d = new PhantomJSDriver();
    d.get(url);
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.findElement(By.id("tbUsername")).sendKeys(userName);
```

I am getting the below error on last line of above code :

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: TypeError - undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')
```

I am using binary PhantomJS and getting the above error for mac and linux system.

Also got multiple post on different forum that PhantomJS can't work with polymer Application. Example:

1. [How do you write end-to-end tests for Polymer (JS) based application (circa May 2015)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036762/how-do-you-write-end-to-end-tests-for-polymer-js-based-application-circa-may)
2. https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/445
3. https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/450

Please suggest how can I solve the above problem.

Comment: Should read the post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37384458/4600982

Comment: @Supersharp I tried `executeScript` method and it did not work. I am getting  this error : `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache"`